# How to append custom text in ngModel in angular 6?

Tags: angular6

I have a code like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="rate" formControlName="rate">
```

This works fine.

**Tried**

1) I just want to append `%` with ngModel. I have tried to use  it with `<span>` tag but I'm facing some `css` issue.

2) `[(ngModel)]="rate + '%'"`
    `Got syntax error.`

3) From **.ts** file :

{ rate: `${0}%` }         //Got `NaN` value in `HTML`

Comment: Well, when you've put `type=number`, the error is pretty much self explanatory. If you want to append a non-digit character, change the type to text and validate the input to being a number with a custom function.

Comment: @AkashSrivastav Sorry , It's just a type. It's already a `text`.

Comment: I meant that in the input tag, you've specified the type to be number, and are trying to assign a non-number value to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this way.

```
  <label >{{rate}}%</label>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have just changed the same thing and it works.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve by below code :

```js
/*in your ts file*/

public changeRate(e){
  if(this.name != ''){
    if (this.name[this.name.length - 1] != "%"){
      this.name += '%';
      console.log(this.name);
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="changeRate()" [(ngModel)]="rate" value="{{name}}" formControlName="rate">
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have tried this but it's not working. So can you please share the example so I can check it...

Comment: I have changed my answer and it works in my case, please check it.